# Showing a specific image in Excel depending on highest value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a really hard time writing a code for this. 
We hence four cells with variable values, a picture should appear depending on the cell with the highest value when a button is clicked.

Example: If cell A1's value is higher than the other cells, picture A should show up when a button is clicked, if cell B1's value is higher, then picture B, which is assigned to that cell, should appear.

We tried our best but couldn't find a solution, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you post the code from your approach?

Comment: You did not try very hard to find a solution, I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9198097/excel-vba-if-cell-value-equals-then-show-hide-images

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is something trivial, but here is how I would do it:

```
Public Sub ShowPic()
    Me.s1.Visible = b_is_visible(Me.s1.Name)
    Me.s2.Visible = b_is_visible(Me.s2.Name)
End sub

Public Function b_is_visible(str_name As String) As Boolean

    If str_name = cells(1,1) Then 
        b_is_visible = True
    end if

End Function
```

In  cell A1 you should put the name of the image. Thus, based on it, the image would be either visible or not. The Images should be in a form. The code above is in the form.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of solutions. One of them is to have some folder with pictures you wanna display, and name them as rows with max value. E.g. if max value is in row 3, the `picture3.jpg` file would be displayed.

```
Sub test123()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRow As Integer, maxVal As Integer

Set Rng = Range("A1:A4")
maxVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rng)
picNum = Application.Match(maxVal, Rng, 0)

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert("K:\user files\user 1\pictures\picture" & picNum & ".jpg").Select

End Sub
```

EDIT:

If you like to reposition image, you can do it by renaming it and using some commends.

```
Selection.ShapeRange.Name = "Pic1"
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Pic1").Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Left
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Pic1").Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 2).Top
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Pic1").Height = ActiveSheet.Range("G1:G7").Height
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Pic1").Width = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:G1").Width
```